# delete item from Activity after receive it in Fragment / Lifecycle issue

Tags: android, lifecycle

I need some help. I've got activity where I create item. Next I want to send it to the fragment in second activity so I need to firstly send it to that Activity (am I correct ?). This is how I create item :

```
public void savePart() {
        Part part = new Part(name,quantity,"","",tag,"","2");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InvActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Part", (Serializable) part);
        setResult(2,intent);
        finish();
    }
```

This is how I receive it in second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 2) {
        part = (Part) data.getSerializableExtra("Part");
    }
}
```

I've got method to return the part in fragment :

```
public Part getMyData() {
        return part;
    }
```

In Fragment's onResume() I receive the Part object, check if object with similar code exists and add it to the ListView if not:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    List<Part>subList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (mActivity.getMyData() != null) {
        Part part = mActivity.getMyData();
        for(Part parts : mParts) {
            if (parts.getCode().contains(part.getCode())) {
                subList.add(parts);
            }
        }
        if (subList.size() == 0) {
            mParts.add(part);
            adapter = new PartAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.part_item, mParts, mActivity, new AdapterCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCallback() {

                }
            });
            mPartsLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.equipment_exists, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

So far everything works well. items are added correctly and shown in ListVIew in fragment.Here is where the problem begins :) In listView row I've got imageView which deletes item from ListView.

```
mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mParts.remove(part);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

That works great to but ... when fragment comes back to onResume() deleted item shows again is ListView. That is because each time I receive Part and check if exists in List. I think I should somehow clear intent after receiving Part from Activity where Part was created but I don't know how ? Maybe any other solution,please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `subList` as public and populate it once. So you need to modify your `onResume` function a bit. Check if the list is populated already. If not, populate the list from the extras and vice versa.

Comment: You mean I should use boolean to check if list was updated ? :)

Comment: Thanks! :) it helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

ListsubList = new ArrayList<>();
your list is created every time when onResume() called that's why delete entries could not managed. So either take a copy of this list or every time check which elements got deleted,and then set data to listview.